# Designing a load test in JMeter - example scenario

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I want to design an API load test (REST API) using JMeter. This is example scenario:

For the first test run, we want to run 1000 virtual users, ramp-up 30 mins, hold target rate time (sustain load 1k users) for 1 hour, and lastly ramp-down 30 mins.

How do I apply this design test? I'm pretty confused whether to use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) or [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) because Concurrency Thread group don't have the Step Down feature.

Here's the example test design using Concurrency Thread Group:

[image]

And this is using Ultimate Thread Group:

[image]

Kindly advise which plugin is suitable for my test scenario. Let me know if you need additional input from me. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency Thread Group indeed "don't have the Step Down feature" however if you connect it to the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) via the [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) you will have the possibility to perform the gradual "ramp-down".

With regards to "which plugin is suitable for my test scenario" - we don't know, the one which delivers the workload you're looking for is "suitable"

Personally I would rather go for:

- If you need to simulate "users" like real persons using real API clients - Ultimate Thread Group
- If you need to conduct the load of "X requests per second" - Concurrency Thread Group

Comment: Ultimate Thread Group can apply step down?